# How can I access the current fullPath inside of a axios plugin in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to get the current path through `route.fullPath` from within a Nuxt plugin for Axios. It is working to a degree, but it looks like because it is coming from the context, it is only ever setting the path when the page was initially loaded. How can I get the current `route.fullPath` (after any route changes) at the time of the Axios error to show?

```js
export default function ({ $axios, store, route, redirect }) {
  $axios.onError((error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      store.commit('misc/setRedirect', route.fullPath);

      redirect('/sign-in');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems like a bug, but as a workaround, you could get the current route through [`app.router.currentRoute`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute) of the plugin's `app` parameter:

```js
// plugins/axios.js
export default function ({ $axios, app }) {
  $axios.onError(error => {
    console.log(error, app.router.currentRoute)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! I have created an issue with the nuxt-community/axios-module to determine if it is indeed a bug.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/295